# Reversible string compression PHP/C++

Tags: php, c++, algorithm, compression, obfuscation

I would like to obfuscate some short text data, and make this compression learnable/memorizable.

So I'm looking for an algorithm achievable in PHP to compress a string (~25 characters long) into a ~8 character string, then reversible in C++.

Does anyone have an algo name or another idea ?

**EDIT**: Everything is lowcase, with two specials characters.

Comment: what does the text data consist of? lowercase, uppercase, digit? any other character?

Comment: Everything is lowcase, with some specials characters.

Comment: How many special characters? I am asking because its required to design the encoding scheme.

Comment: Only two specials characters will be used

Comment: Did you ever try to compress a ZIP archive twice? You would have noted that compressing an already compressed archive won't reduce its size any further. The same holds for your strings, there will always be strings which cannot be compressed any further. Which means: you can only have an *average* compression rate from e.g. 25 to 8 characters, and there will always be exceptions. Unless of course by compressing you actually mean encoding with a bigger alphabet where each character stores more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible.

If we assume that the original strings only contains letters A-Z, there are 26<sup>25</sup> ≈ 4.25 x 10<sup>37</sup> (42 billion billion billion billion) possible input strings.

If we then generously allow the eight-character outputs to contain any letter, uppercase or lowercase, or digit (26 + 26 + 10 = 62 characters total), there are 62<sup>8</sup> ≈ 2.18 x 10<sup>14</sup> (218 million billion) possible outputs.

This is roughly 10<sup>23</sup> times fewer! By the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), the compression scheme you're asking for is impossible -- there are *many* times more possible input strings than outputs, so there's no way to reversibly turn every one of the input strings into an output and back.

Comment: So algo like CRC-16 encoding don't make unique output strings ?

Comment: @Bloo2 Nope! For instance, `"plumless"` and `"buckeroo"` both have CRC32 0x4ddb0c25. (That's CRC32, not CRC16, but there will only be _more_ collisions for a shorter hash.)

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for explanations.

Answer (score 0):

As the text data only consists of lowercase letters and two special characters, so we have only 28 different characters to consider.

We can design the hash function by property of bit representation. With all possible combination of 5 bits, we can uniquely represent 32 different symbols. So, to represent 28 different symbols, we only need 5 bits for each symbol.

```
a => 00000
b => 00001
c => 00010
......
......
......
y => 11000
z => 11001
special-character-1 => 11010
special-character-2 => 11011
```

With this encoding scheme, we only need 25 * 5 = 125 bits to represent the complete text data, which is 125 / 8 ~ 16 bytes or 16 characters (sorry its not 8 characters).

Now, you can retrieve the actual string from this 16 characters hash by applying the reverse mapping.

If you're satisfied with 16 characters reversible hashing, I can provide C++ implementation.

Comment: Nice idea. But even if I can simulate output string fixed length, 16 chars is really too much to memorize... Not to mention it appear to me that coding this on 5 bits will be difficult to display chars in output.

Comment: Yes, sadly some of the generated characters won't be ASCII or displayable too but it will work surely.

Comment: I need this compression memorizable.

Comment: 16 bytes is considered memorizable because people memorise MD5 hash usually. How many hash will you have?

Comment: Users will only have one hash to remember, but ask to remember 16 chars will be difficult for them. Less than 10 is ok I guess, 8 would be ok.